# Наложение водяного знака на изображение в боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pil

Имеется 2 хэндлера в FSM. Принимают от пользователя 2 фотографии. 1 изображение = куда хотят наложить водяной знак, 2 изображение = сам водяной знак.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=Groupuser.photo)
async def load_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['photo'] = message.photo[0].file_id

    await message.answer('Теперь отправь изображение водяного знака')
    await Groupuser.next()

@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=Groupuser.znak)
async def load_znak(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['znak'] = message.photo[1].file_id

    image1 = Image.open(data['photo'])
    image2 = Image.open(data['znak'])
    image3 = Image.blend(image1, image2, 0.5)
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=image3)
```

При отправке пользователю результата выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-18' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\тг бот тест\photo_redact.py", line 54, in load_znak
    image1 = Image.open(data['photo'])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3227, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AgACAgIAAxkBAANsZEZUCnYN2ddzbLShMSyMvOQ70gYAAv3EMRuesDBKqYuxcwMok5oBAAMCAANzAAMvBA'
```

Comment: Выдает не такую ошибку! В ошибке намного больше текста. Добавьте ВЕСЬ текст ошибки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то не вижу я в документации по [`.send_photo`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_photo) параметра **photo**.
Но, ладно, может версии разные, или библиотека другая, например [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57485175/8489602) передают binary. Ваш `image3` это не binary объект, а `PIL.Image.Image`, бот не знает что с ним делать, пытается открыть как файл, из-за чего выдаёт ошибку.

Можно сохранить изображение на диск и присылать его. Но если нет желания сохранять на диск, то можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29817798/8489602):

```python
import io
output = io.BytesIO()
image3.save(output, format='PNG')
```

И затем передавать через `photo=output.getvalue()`.

Comment: Выдает такую ошибку
image1 = Image.open(data['photo'], 'r')
 fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAPaZEaraUE-idm_4u9Mw_YReUwiunkAAlbJMRt42TBKXLiI19QFj0UBAAMCAANzAAMvBA'

Comment: @KARL вы точно все изменения внесли? Попробуйте сохранять в файл и передавать файл.